# R and Daily Projects

Tags: r, project

I'm now reading some books of **[R](http://www.r-project.org/)**, but I want to know if I can use this language as I use Perl or Ruby. Things like:

- Image Processing
- File Compression
- Use APIs
- Interact With Internet

But it's usual and simple(as in Perl or Ruby) to do things like this?

PS: I liked this language very much, because of this I want to use it on my personal projects and spread it for my friends and at the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CRAN Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) are reasonable starting points.  So in order

- Image processing: see [Graphics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Graphics.html) and [MedicalImaging](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html)
- File compression: accessible from Base R, so try `help(connection)`
- Use APIs: you will need to ask that question again, if you mean language bindings: yes, plenty, though no one single page for all
- Interact with Internet:  see above on `help(connection)`, there are also packages that wrap curl, provide SOAP and of course the XML package.

*Edit:* And I forgot to stress that [R](http://www.r-project.org) as a *statistical language and environment* is more domain-specific than either Ruby or Python so the comparisons aren't entirely appropriate. But you can also code Gtk2 guis in R if you feel like it...

Comment: My pleasure.  But please don't toss random bold face into my posts.  Common courtesy on SO is often to suggests an edit in a comment to another user.

Comment: Nobody can. But you did edit my post and I am suggesting you should not have.

Comment: Ok, I'm so sorry, can you forgive me becacuse of this mistake? Thanks.